# Node.js request download file sometimes empty or no existing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, download, request

I'm writing a downloader with node.js and the request module. Using the stream syntax I'm doing

```
var r = request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(targetPath));
r.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
r.on('finish', cb);
```

to download the file, save it and call the callback. However, in almost 50% of the cases the file is either empty or not created at all. No `error` event is emitted. It seems like the `finish` event is triggered even though the file wasn't (completely) written yet.

Context: The whole thing is wrapped into `async.each` calls.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: try debugging by also adding a `.on('data'` listener and see if you're always receiving the data but it's just not making it to disk.

Answer (score 12):

You need to close the file before accessing it:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
var r = request(url).pipe(file);
r.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
r.on('finish', function() { file.close(cb) });
```

Incidentally, if the url replies with any http error (such as a 404 not found), that won't trigger the 'error' event, so you should probably check that separately:

```
function handleFailure(err) { console.log(err); };

var file = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
request(url, function(error, response) {
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log("oops, got a " + response.statusCode);
        return
    }
    // close is async, and you have to wait until close completes otherwise
    // you'll (very rarely) not be able to access the file in the callback.
    file.on('finish', function() { file.close(cb) });

    response.pipe(file).on('error', handleFailure)
    file.on('error', handleFailure)
}).on('error', handleFailure);
```